# Horizontal scrollable Textview not working

Tags: android

This is the xml file for scroll the textview,but it is not working.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_join_crew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/join_my_crew"
    android:textSize="@dimen/content_text_size" >
</TextView>
```

this is the xml code and it is not working.

Comment: `textview.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);` add it dynamically and try it.

Comment: thanks for reply, but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code work but you have add this code in java

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_join_crew);
 tv.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: what is problem or any error occure in this then tell me ?

Comment: this is not automatic scrolling

Comment: @MonuGupta glad to help you.